# Command :hover - change the background color of the 4 divs

Tags: html, hover

I would like to get the effect of changing the background color of 4 divs. I managed to get the effect of changing the background color of the two - if anyone could help me with the other two?
link:
jsfiddle.net/WU4eJ/

Answer (score 0):

I would try using general sibling selectors (~) and not only adjacent sibling selectors (+)